# Remoting references by wrapping them in a MarshalByRefObject? Will it work?

Tags: plugins, remoting, maf, marshalbyrefobject

I'm trying to implement a plugin system using MAF.  The objects I want to pass currently aren't serializable though, and even though I'm sure I could make them serializable I don't think it would be very performant.

Two questions:

1) In order for MAF to pass the actual references across, does an object simply need to inherit from MarshalByRefObject or is there more to it than that?

2) Could I wrap my class in an object that inherits from MarshalByRefObject to get the reference across?

EDIT:  Obviously the problem itself has little to do with MAF, but I just wanted to include some context in case someone could point me in an altogether direction to go.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, it just needs to inherit from MarshalByRefObject, but any public types inside the class also need to be serializable or inherit from MarshalByRefObject as well.

2) No, this just pushes the problem back since the class still needs to be serializable or inherit from MarshalByRefObject.